# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'servicios' of undefined" Vue.js + Vuefire

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

So what i want to do is filter the data retrieved from firebase real time database when user selects a category from a select component and fill the filtered data to another select, filling it with all the data succeds but when i try to filter it based on the selection i get the error:
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVkUN.png)

Here is my component code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
          <div class="card-body">


            <h3>Ingresar requerimiento</h3>
            <div v-if="user" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Sesión Iniciada Exitosamente!</div>
             CATEGORIA:
            <b-form-select v-model="selectedCategory" :options="options" size="sm" class="mt-3"></b-form-select>
            <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selectedCategory }}</strong></div>
             SOPORTE:

             <b-form-select v-model="selectedSoporte" size="sm" class="mt-3">
               <option v-for="soporte in ComputedServicios" :value="soporte.nombre" :key="soporte.codigo ">{{ soporte.nombre }}</option>

             </b-form-select>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { db } from '../firebase';
import firebase from "firebase";
import {servsRef} from '../firebase'
Vue.use(db)
Vue.use(firebase)
//Vue.use(servsRef)

console.log(db);

export default {

   firebase: {
    servicios: servsRef
  },

  computed: {
    // map `this.user` to `this.$store.getters.user`
    ...mapGetters({
      user: "user"
    }),
   ComputedServicios: () => {
     //var vm = this;
     const data = this.servicios
    return data.filter(function (soporte) {
      if(soporte.categoria==this.selectedCategory)
      return soporte
    })
  }
  },


   data() {
      return {

       // servicios: [],
       vm : this,

        selectedSoporte:null,
        selectedCategory: null,
        options: [
          { value: null, text: 'Elija la categoría del soporte' },
          { value: 'electrico', text: 'Eléctrico' },
          { value: 'hidraulico', text: 'Hidráulico' },
          { value: 'electronico', text: 'Electrónico' },
          { value: 'mecanico', text: 'Mecánico'},
          { value: 'neumatico', text: 'Neumático'}
        ]
      }
    }

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite ComputedServicios without the arrow function.

```js
ComputedServicios()  {
    return this.servicios.filter(soporte => soporte.categoria == this.selectedCategory)
}
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, **although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target** keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.